# How do I re-install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo?

Tags: package-management, themes, 20.04, plymouth

I had KDE installed on my computer a bit ago. Switched back to gnome in 18.04. Recently upgraded to 20.04 and realized the Kubuntu loading screen still shows on startup. Did some research and found info on plymouth themes.

Went to change it and was disappointed to find that `ubuntu-logo` was not in my themes folder. Furthermore, `apt search plymouth-theme` gives me a list with `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo/now 0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.2 amd64 [residual-config]`. When I run `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` (found on an AskUbuntu answer from 2014), only kubuntu and bgrt are listed.

I tried to re-install the ubuntu-logo theme with `sudo apt install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo`, but got:

```
Package plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo' has no installation candidate
```

How can I re-install the default ubuntu-logo plymouth theme?

Comment: Changes were made with the way plymouth is used on 20.04 (so as to allow OEM logos to show thru not being covered by the plymouth), thus old plymouth themes are gone & replaced (except by Lubuntu anyway). I didn't look for a fix/solution for you, just FYI on why changes occurred in 20.04/focal and why older themes are gone. My own *groovy* system has plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo:
 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6 found in 'universe', do you have 'universe' enabled?

Comment: bgrt is the default background logo for 20.04. Select it, and the kubuntu screen will be gone.

Comment: @guiverc I must've disabled universe while upgrading to 20.04. Enabled it and was able to install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo.

Comment: @heynnema That helps a bunch, not sure why that wasn't more clear on google. I noticed the bgrt is considerably faster bootup and shutdown than the kubuntu plymouth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

In `terminal`...

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

And choose `bgrt`, which is the default boot screen in 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue on ubuntu, when I run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

I get

> update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for default.plymouth

whatever I do from install perspective on the machine I get:

> 1 not fully installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/24.2 kB of archives.
> After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. dpkg:
> error processing package plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo (--configure):
> package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should  reinstall it
> before attempting configuration Errors were encountered while
> processing:  plymouth-theme-xubuntu-logo needrestart is being skipped
> since dpkg has failed E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error
> code (1)

Comment: This should be a comment rather than a suggested solution